# Cannot install ethernet driver

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, ethernet

I've been having problems with my ethernet lately, it disconnects randomly and says I'm connected to an "Unidentified network":

[image]

I then tried a number of things, including deleting the driver with the intention of re-installing it, the problem is when I connect to the internet it says no drivers found:

[image]

I've also tried going to the Dell website and downloaded both the Chipset drivers (Intel Chipset Software Installation Utility) and the Network drivers (Broadcom 57XX Gigabit Integrated Controller) with no luck either.

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/vostro-430/drivers

Finally I downloaded Dell's System Detect, but that didn't find any drivers either:

[image]

Any advice would be very appreciated... thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use a software that detects drivers (it might work)

- [Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect)
- [DriverPack Solution](http://drp.su/)
- [Driver Detective](http://www.drivershq.com/)

or see what chipsets you have and download them from the manufacturer

Comment: Thank you very much! The intel driver update worked great :)